# How to Convert POSIX time as regular date and time in Spark 2?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark & Pyspark, and just started with spark 2.0. I am trying to convert time stamp from server (In POSIX/Unix format) into regular date ( such as yyyy-mm-dd & time), but unable to do so. I have used the following two commands:

```
df_new = df.withColumn('fromTimestamp', f.from_unixtime(df['timestamp'], 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss'))
```

and

```
 df.select("timestamp",from_unixtime(f.col("timestamp"))).show()
```

where f is alias for pyspark.sql.functions API. They both produce the following result:

```
|   @RequiredResult  |   ActualResult     |
+--------------------+--------------------+
|2020-06-01 00:00:03 |52385-52-27 00:52:14|
|2020-06-01 00:00:02 |52385-35-27 00:35:19|

+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Furthermore, I want to aggregate time intervals (to 30 min or 60 min)durations. Any leads on how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should avoid asking multiple questions at the same time. This makes it more difficult to answer your posts. So you could post a second question about the time intervals. But maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48302543/2129801) already answers your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unix timestamp is defined as the number of seconds since 1 January 1970. However some unix-like systems use the number of **milli**seconds since this date, producing 1000 times higher values.

For example the date `2020-06-01 00:00:03` would be represented by the timestamp `1590962403`. If the timestamp `1590962403000` was used, this would result in a date of the year 52385:

```python
spark.sql("""select from_unixtime(1590962403) as seconds, 
                    from_unixtime(1590962403000) as ms""")\
        .show(truncate=False)
```

prints

```
+-------------------+---------------------+
|seconds            |ms                   |
+-------------------+---------------------+
|2020-06-01 00:00:03|+52385-08-04 18:50:00|
+-------------------+---------------------+
```

So you should divide the `timestamp` column by 1000 before applying `from_unixtime`.